# Saving fields and loading them

Tags: php, html, variables

I am making a program for my diving coach that calculates the dive score as the judges enter their judgement. The problem I am having is all the fields clear themselves when I press submit. Additionally, I would like to be able to save the dive sheet and be able to reload the data within after navigating away, reloading, or closing and reopening. Maybe later allow for multiple sheets of different dates per diver, but I can do that later.

I am also hiding a lot of errors from setting variables from my $_GET code, it would be filling a lot of space with warnings.

This is my code:

```
<tr>
<td>
<form action='guest6.php' method='GET'>
1. <input placeholder='Judge 1 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1A'>
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Judge 2 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1B'>
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Judge 3 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1C'>
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Enter DD' autocomplete='off' name='DD1'> 
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<?php
if (($_GET["Score1A"] != '') || ($_GET["Score1B"] != '') || ($_GET["Score1C"] != ''))
{
    $J1A = $_GET["Score1A"];
    $J1B = $_GET["Score1B"];
    $J1C = $_GET["Score1C"];
    $DD1 = $_GET["DD1"];
    echo $score1 = ($J1A + $J1A + $J1A) * $DD1;

}    
?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `value="<?php echp $_GET['Score1A']; ?>"` or similar in your `input`'s could give it a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<tr>
<td>
<form action='guest6.php' method='GET'>
1. <input placeholder='Judge 1 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1A' value='<?php echo $_GET["Score1A"];?>'>
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Judge 2 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1B' value="<?php echo $_GET["Score1B"];?>">
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Judge 3 Score' autocomplete='off' name='Score1C' value="<?php echo $_GET["Score1C"];?>">
</td>
<td>
    <input placeholder='Enter DD' autocomplete='off' name='DD1'> 
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<?php
    if (($_GET["Score1A"] != '') || ($_GET["Score1B"] != '') || ($_GET["Score1C"] != ''))
    {
        $J1A = $_GET["Score1A"];
        $J1B = $_GET["Score1B"];
        $J1C = $_GET["Score1C"];
        $DD1 = $_GET["DD1"];
        echo $score1 = ($J1A + $J1A + $J1A) * $DD1;
}    
?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value for each input can solve the problem:

```
value="<?=$_GET['Score1A']?>"
```

Moreover, if you want to save the vote for later you should use the cookie, set the value with the setcookie function and then retrieve them with the $_COOKIE array.

Comment: Thank you both. Setting value should have been obvious lol...I will look into $_COOKIE arrays tomorrow.

Comment: can you upvote (both) and mark one of the posts as your answer?

Comment: No, I can't upvote either. I don't have the rep.

setting the value of the GET forms works for each individual field, but the code I showed above repeats 11 times and each submit button clears the old one. I am learning mysql in my programming class next week, so I'm sure I'll be able to fix it then.